# Авторизация данными из Wordpress на левом сайте, как организовать?

Tags: php, wordpress, авторизация

Здравствуйте! Как можно авторизироваться на отдельном сайте, использующую одну бд с WP, используя данный от WP?

Знаю что, WP использует микрофраемворк Phpass, знаю, что соли хранятся в wp-config, но доков по phpass не смог найти..

Есть ли другие варианты?

PS. Отдельный сайт написан на PHP

Comment: Решение в лоб: проверять валидность данных, авторизуя на WordPress, делать редирект с определенным токеном на целевой сайт, на целевом сайте проверять токен и если он верен, то авторизовывать встроенными методами (если такие есть) по имени пользователя без проверки пароля. Вот сам [PHPass](https://github.com/rchouinard/phpass).

Comment: Было бы славно, если бы вы указали еще и на чем у вас написан "отдельный сайт".

Comment: Добавил, хотя по тегам это было видно :)

Comment: Я имел в виду конкретный фреймворк или CMS. Язык понятен. Инструмент - нет. Хорошо, что вопрос решен.

Comment: все пишется с 0 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если отдельный сайт расположен на этом же сервере, то смотрим в настройках сессии wordpress путь до её хранения, при редиректе передаём session_id после стартуем сессию по этому id в своём приложение

```
session_id($_GET('sid'));
session_start();
```

так вы получите доступ к сессии вордпресса где и сможете проверить авторизован или нет юзер.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь